# F#: Is there an idiomatic way to replace for loops seq{} expressions?

Tags: f#

Is there a more idiomatic way to express this pattern in F#:

```
seq {
    for item1 in list1 do 
        for item2 in list2 do
            yield f(item1,item2)
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This pattern is as idiomatic as it gets.

Usually an alternative is to use a pipeline of higher-order functions like `Seq.map` or `Seq.filter`, but for your particular case - Cartesian product - 
a sequence comprehension approach really shines and you won't get anything near that simple otherwise.

Utlimately it's a judgement call which style to use. I tend to prefer the pipeline approach, only to later realize how much clearer a sequence comprehension approach is.

Comment: just as a comment - you need `Seq.collect` or `Seq.concat` (the monadic methods) to *translate*  something with more than one `for` in it (should be the case as it makes no sense to use `seq { ... }` over a simple `map` or `filter` otherwise.

Comment: @CarstenKönig: true - an actual example of how to implement it using `Seq.map` nested in `Seq.collect` is in the linked thread. As for not using comprehensions for simple mapping/filtering - I think there are some who would disagree (I think Tomas Petricek recently wrote that he prefers that style).

Answer (score 1):

As long, as you don't need anything complicated, like imperative features or flattening of sub-expressions (`yield!`), you can use a slightly less verbose syntax:

```
seq { for item1 in list1 do
      for item2 in list2 -> f(item1, item2) }
```

Comment: this *will* **flatten** the yields from the second `for` ;)

Comment: i meant more like tree traversal, where you are combining flattening of a child tree with yielding a single element